# native module must not be null - RCTSystemSetting

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm trying to use the react-native-system-setting library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-system-setting

When I try to import the file:

```
import SystemSetting from 'react-native-system-setting';
```

I get this error:

[image: ios-error-native-module-must-not-be-null]

I've successfully linked the module by adding it to my Podfile:

[image: podfile]

Here it is in xcode!

[image: xcode]

The module is clearly installed and not null so what is wrong here? A pathing issue? It seems to pull in every other module just fine so what is wrong with this one?

Comment: 1.- You don't have to manually link. 2.- `pod install`, if `pod install is not working`, open an issue in the library github's page.

Comment: I just tried removing the entry in the pod file and running ```pod install``` again... the library disappears and I get the same error